# Rails migration: Add two references to one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am having a hard time extending an existing model to include two references to a single table.

My current model is called `Order` and I need two references (`payment_state` and `delivery_state`) to the `State` table.

It is my understanding that I should run the following command:

```
rails g migration AddStatesToOrder payment_state:references delivery_state:references
```

However, the following line comes up in my `schema.rb` after running `rake db:migrate`:

```
# Could not dump table "orders" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
rails g migration AddStatesToOrder payment_state_id:integer delivery_state_id:integer
```

And define the relation like this in the model:

```
belongs_to :payment_state, class_name: State.model_name
belongs_to :delivery_state, class_name: State.model_name
```

Why using :integer instead of :references? Because the thing you want to do is not "conventional", it is a customized double-relation to the same model, and Rails cannot guess it for you.